# How do I convert a similar MySQL query to Laravel Eloquent?

Tags: mysql, laravel

```
SELECT * FROM `books` WHERE books.type = 'rare' AND books.band - $value < $result
```

That's how I think it should be

```
$books= DB::table('books')
                        ->where('type ','=', 'rare')
                        ->whereRaw('band - $value < $result')   // Syntax error
```

I don't understand how to work with dynamic variables here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try it:

```
$books= DB::table('books')
            ->where('type ', 'rare')
            ->whereRaw('band - ? < ?', [$value, $result])
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

try use parenthesis, it's simple:

```
 $books= DB::table('books')
            ->where('type ','=', 'rare')
            ->whereRaw("band - {$value} < {$result}")->get();
```

you can do it using binding also:

```
 $books= DB::table('books')
            ->where('type ','=', 'rare')
            ->whereRaw("band - ? < ?",[$value,$result])->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
$books= DB::table('books')
       ->where('type ','=', 'rare')
       ->whereRaw(\DB::raw("band - $value < $result"))
       ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Always use Eloquent with laravel.

```
$books = Books::where('type','rare')->whereRaw("band - $value < $result")->get();
```